# How should an unused knob and tube run be terminated?

Tags: electrical, knob-and-tube, old-work

What are the safe and compliant options for terminating an unused knob and tube branch? In this instance, insulation will be applied, so the fixtures and receptacles previously on this circuit have been wired to a completely separate circuit of Romex. This is on a third floor, far away from the panel.

I had an electrician complete this work, but I’m not very confident in the mess of wires he left in the attic. What type of termination should I be looking for in order to feel comfortable proceeding with insulation?

Wires in cavity between roof and 3rd floor ceiling:
[image: Wires in cavity between roof and 3rd floor ceiling]
A wire nut can be seen in the open air

Comment: How about some pictures so we can see what you see.

Comment: @JACK I added an image. A wire nut can be seen on one of the connections. I didn’t test all of them, but I believe (and hope) all of the wires without nuts are not live

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on there but it looks a little scary.  When I have had to rework a portion of  K&T,  I have always removed as much as possible the cable/wire I was eliminating  and did all splicing from K&T to NM cable in junction boxes that would remain accessible.

Comment: Is putting a junction box in there an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I don’t see why not. I think perhaps the only reason he didn’t is because it was near the end of the day when I reminded him insulation will be installed. I said I wanted all of the K&T disconnected, so he removed an existing connection (to an unused branch) shortly before leaving. All of this kind of points to a rushed job to me, he was just planning on leaving an unnecessary connection in place before I asked. And even further, I hope I can just terminate this in the basement instead of running to the attic on 100+ year old wire for no reason

Comment: Sounds like that nut violates NEC 300.15. I’ll have him come back and fix it

Comment: I would verify that the branch is unused. I am with Jack removing unused portions is a good idea.

Comment: Cut at both ends and therefore unquestionably defunct. I'm unaware of any code that says you have to remove anything that is defunct. "What type of termination should I be looking for?" That there's nothing but new wires coming into the load center, and every single junction box in the entire unit; "***all*** of the K&T disconnected" - if they did that then w/e. It can still be hooked to other k&t, all of which is disconnected and never to be used again; cut at both *ends*, not everywhere in between.

Comment: What you asked them to do was stupid and they were like *wtf ever then*, which is not best practice; leave their connections alone; not flying off into space, should it ever (mistakenly) be re-powered.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to go double check my NEC before saying for certain, but my recollection is that unless specifically tagged for future use old wiring no longer in service is supposed to be entirely removed. Now, there is some question of the practicality of that when the wiring is not in conduit, etc. but I would suggest getting as much removed as practical before insulating. Getting rid of all of it would be best practice. You also want to be very sure that if any of it is still hooked up anywhere it does not get buried in insulation.

Comment: While that's true for some things (comms wiring, most notably), there's no generic Chapter 3 requirement for removing unused wiring.  It's definitely a good idea to not leave it lurking around, though, especially if it's obsolete the way the OP's is.

Comment: Another reason for removing it is that the KT wiring may pick up (harmless) levels of phantom voltage. This could show up on a non-contact voltage tester later at some other point along the same wire and cause expensive confusion about what is live and what is out of service.